# Converting time zones

Tags: sql-server, timezone

My SQL Server is located in US Mountain Standard Time where the Daylight Savings is not observed. My office is in US Central time zone. All schedules are kept in Central time by business.

I am trying to figure out how to allow business to enter job schedules in a table in Central time and convert those to Mountain, taking Daylight Savings into account.

TIA!

Comment: So all data is stored as central time (with DST already taken into account) and you just want mountain time users to see / search based on their time zone? What version of SQL Server are you using? Can you show some sample data? Personally I'm a fan of storing UTC (since it's far easier to convert from UTC to any time zone with or without DST than it is to convert from one time zone to another, especially when one has DST and the other doesn't). Jon Skeet has a different opinion: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

Comment: Daylight savings is the trick I am trying to figure out without resorting to calculation. The point is only one of the side of the conversion is affected by DST. Whether the other side is Mountain or UTC, doesn't really matter.

Comment: The version of SQL Server is important. `AT TIME ZONE` may suit your needs, see [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-plan/at-time-zone) and [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/t-sql-queries/using-at-time-zone-to-fix-an-old-report).

Comment: 2012 and 2016, AT TIME ZONE and DATETIMEOFFSET require the offset hours parameter, while Mountain is always -07:00, Central changes between -05:00 AND -06:00. I was hoping there is a way of getting that offset from the server.

Comment: The server may know the offset _right now_ (depending on the server's own timezone settings), but it won't magically apply the offset for a date in the past or the future. `AT TIME ZONE` just requires the name of the time zone, here is a better example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=73ba0e561a69b6fd2908f5698e5f1302

Comment: That fiddle assumes the times are stored in UTC.  If the stored dates are Central Standard Time, it would be `AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'US Mountain Standard Time'`.

Comment: @David the fiddle didn't store any data, it was just demonstrating that you can take a date/time from any time zone (I chose UTC) and translate it to another time zone (I demonstrated both) without having to specify an offset (I was just addressing the OP's comment: `AT TIME ZONE ... require the offset hours parameter`).

Comment: It sure does make it easier if you store all dates in UTC though.

Comment: I didn't realize AT TIME ZONE can use the name and sys.time_zone_info is definitely a great addition. Now to figure out what to do on the 2012 server. Need to put up with it for another 6-12 months.